# UK Tier 1, enter before starting date?

Tags: visas, uk

I've received my visa Tier 1 'exceptional talent' today starting 1st November. I have a flight a few days before (27th October).

Is there any reason to be worried?

I can, in theory change my flight dates, but I have a trip on these days.

I don't require visa just to enter to the UK if it matters at all.

Comment: i THINK, but i don't know, you would have to enter again to get the work visa per se stamped in your passport.  also, what pnuts said.

Comment: Im Israeli, so in theory I can get in few days before as a tourist (I dont need visa for this)?

Comment: It's a double-edged sword that can have hidden consequences. Please read the canonical.

Comment: Ok, so the thing is that I have a field trip few days before the visa starts. I can get a formal letter explaining why I need to enter the uk before (as a tourist), Then to leave and to come back...is there a potential problem with this?

Comment: Also, Im planning to go abroad for a day and then came back, will this be a problem?